# Jenkins on Windows: UE4 packaging for iOS fails with "Host key verification failed."

Tags: python, windows, jenkins, unreal-engine4

I have this Jenkins server running on my Windows machine. What the jobs do is it runs some python code that is also on the same machine, to package .ipa file (for iOS) using UE4 engine and ships it.

Everything works just fine if I run python code locally. But when I run it through Jenkins, it will fail at some point where UE4 is trying to sign the package. This is partial error message I'm getting.

```
Using remote server 'XXX.YYY.ZZZ.56' on port 22 (user '***********')
[Remote] Using private key at ...\RemoteToolChainPrivate.key
ERROR: Unable to determine home directory for remote user. SSH output:
           Host key verification failed.
```

I think for some reason Jenkins doesn't know where ssh related stuffs are located in windows.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you [installed Jenkins as a Windows Service](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+as+a+Windows+service), then Jenkins is probably running as another user (not the user you sign in as).

In the Services app, you can change the user the service is running as if necessary. You can find the Services app here:

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Administrative Tools\services.lnk
```

[image: Changing the User the Service Uses]

See [About Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/about-services) for more info.

That explains why the remote cannot find the home directory (because the remote user has a different name than the service account user) and also why the host key verification failed (since you never accepted the host key as the service account user).